# What is the relation ship of Google AdSense account and Google Ads Manager account?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ad-manager

I am earning money via Google AdSense account for years. But recently when some ad platform company reaches to me asking about my Google Ad Manager account, I am a bit confused.

What is a Google Ads Manager account for?

I tried to search materials online but failed to find any good articles. Can somebody explain the difference/connection for the GAM and AdSense with some examples?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relationship between the two. Google Ads Manager is for running and paying for your own adverts, within Google Search (and search partners), YouTube, and the display network.

Whereas, as you know, AdSense is for adding your website(s) to the display network.

Unless you are running paid adverts to drive traffic to your site through Google's ad network, there is no reason for you to have a Google Ads Manager account.

It seems that this person from the 'ad platform company' might be confused or assumed you were running paid adverts when you aren't.

Comment: Thanks. If I am the domain owner of example.com, can I create a GAM account to claim I am the owner? I am still confused.

Comment: There's no "claiming" ownership of domains in Ads. You can essentially just target ads at whatever website you like, so long as pay and so long as you abide by the rules.

Comment: Oh, if I said that Google Ads Manager was just the new name for AdWords, would that clarify things?

Comment: In my understanding, AdWords means a platform for the people how want to spend money to buy ads?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. it's for buying ads, as opposed to AdSense which is essentially for selling advertising space. So unless you are buying advertising, you don't need an Ads Manager account.

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that ad buyers (who want to place ads on my website) asks me to *approve* their request in my GAM account. Why is this happening? They said all ad buyers need to do that because Google requested it.